# Angular 4: ngComponentOutlet - data binding

Tags: angular, data-binding

I am trying to bind data to an ng-container that is in Angular 4 now.
The component loads fine, but when I add [componentData]="testing" I get error

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="components.name"  [componentData]="testing">
</ng-container>
```

Error

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'componentData' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'.
1. If 'componentData' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("'Textarea' ">
                                      <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="widget.widgetComponent.component"  [ERROR ->][componentData]="testing">
                                      </ng-container>
                            </div>
```

Is it true you can't bind data to ngComponentOutlet?

Comment: you are having `ng-container` which is used in case of `template`. `[componentData]` is a custom `@Input()` property which is not available as your input.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44281288/reflectiveinjector-is-not-instantiating-component-correctly-with-ngcomponentoutl Here is an alternative https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522633/angular-4-assign-input-for-ngcomponentoutlet-dynamically-created-component

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you can create a custom component

```
'custom-ng-container'

@Input() componentName : any;
@Input() componentData : any[];
```

HTML will look like

```
<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="componentName" >

</ng-container>
```

You should be using in your parent component as

```
<custom-ng-container [componentName]="components.name"  [componentData]="testing"> </custom-ng-container>
```

Comment: So the answear is that you can't :(

Comment: yup. you have limitations of using `*ngContainer`

Comment: Can you updated ur answear please to that it is not possible

Comment: @Aravind i need to read componentData values in loaded component page not in 'custom-ng-container' custom component.Ex: <custom-ng-container [componentName]="components.name"  [componentData]="testing"> </custom-ng-container>  components:[{name:Page.component}]