# ReflectiveInjector is not instantiating component correctly with ngComponentOutlet Directive

Tags: angular, angularjs-directive

Here is an example [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lORryQsmNuvyxsq1iD98). Any help is appreciated!

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component1',
  template : `
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <button (click)='dismiss()'>dismiss</button>
     <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="Component2;
              injector: myInjector;
              content: myContent">
    </ng-container>
  `
})
export class Component1 implements OnInit{
  title : string = "hello!";
  myInjector: Injector;
  myContent: any;
  constructor(private injector : Injector){
    this.myInjector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
        { provide : Component2, useClass : Component2 }, 
        { provide: TestObject, useFactory: ()=> 
          { 
            return new TestObject("123", "hello world!", "<h2>sample</h2>", "{"a":{"b":{"Value":"test"},"c":{"Value":"test 1"}}}");
          }
        }
      ], this.injector);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    var templateParent = document.createElement("div");
    templateParent.innerHTML = "<h2>this is test html!</h2>";
    this.myContent = [templateParent.childNodes];


  }

  dismiss(){
    console.log('dismiss clicked!');
  }
}
```

Comment: moved link from code block to a link, copied relative code from plunker to the question

Answer (score 1):

I don't see `Component2` property in `Component1`. So you're passing `undefined` to `*ngComponentOutlet`

Try the following

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit{
  Component2 = Component2;
```

And you have syntax error

```
"{"a":{"b":{"Value":"test"},"c":{"Value":"test 1"}}}"
```

you should use it as

`'{"a":{"b":{"Value":"test"},"c":{"Value":"test 1"}}}'`

**[Forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sxxDJXIXr3SyS3gCt0HU?p=preview)**