# Angular material tabs using ngComponentOutlet

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using [Angular Material Tabs](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview) to navigate different sections of a document. I've defined each tab in a TabItem class which looks like this:

```
class TabItem {
     constructor(
         public component: Type<any>, 
         public data: TabData,
         public active: boolean
     ) {}
}
```

In the view, I loop through each TabItem and use *ngComponentOutlet to render the component of each TabItem.

```
<mat-tab-group>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
        <mat-tab>
             <ng-template mat-tab-label>
                   <div class="mat-label-text" (click)="setActiveTab(tab)">{{ tab.data.label }}</div>
             </ng-template>

             <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="tab.component"></ng-container>
        </mat-tab>
    </ng-container>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Everything works well... except I need access to the current TabItem in each of the resolved components to access its id, label, etc. The reason I am having trouble is because the examples online only show how to use ngComponentOutlet as a dynamic component. My components arent dynamic though... they are fixed, but created on the fly.

I dont know how I can use an injector since I am in a for loop... unless I create an injector for each individual item. I also dont want to subscribe to a service in every component... thats just ridiculous.

[Here is a stackblitz of what I am trying to accomplish.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5qwxu)

Comment: basiclly you are looking for a way to pass parameters via `*ngComponentOutlet` right? [maybe this answer can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42527095/3470148). It basiclly said this isn't supported and you should use dynamic component which is not what you want, so I don't know if I'm helping you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a directive that will port desired data to your components:

**data-provider.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[dataProvider]'
})
export class DataProviderDirective {
  @Input('dataProvider') data: any;
}
```

**tabs.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
  <mat-tab [dataProvider]="tab">
```

Now your dynamically generated component can read data from that directive:

**tab-one.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataProviderDirective } from './data-provider.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab-one',
  template: `
    <p>I am tab one!</p>
    <p>How can I access my respective TabItem?</p>
    <pre>{{ dataProvider.data | json }}</pre> 
  `,
})
export class TabOneComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dataProvider: DataProviderDirective) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.dataProvider.data)
  }
}
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5qwxu-k4ajyr?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftabs%2Ftab-one.component.ts)**

Comment: @yurzui how did you know to put the directive on `mat-tab` selector? For some reason I thought the directive should be on `ng-container` that contains the `*ngComponentOutlet` directive since the component is instantiate into this `ng-container`, very interested in knowing how this works.

Comment: `NgComponentOutlet` directive looks at parentInjector by default https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/78b8d0e1ef8a646d91009e48b2dab85a3ea0fbc3/packages/common/src/directives/ng_component_outlet.ts#L88