# How to assign value of *ngFor loop variable to angular dynamic component's @Input property?

Tags: angular, ng-component-outlet

Here is complete rewrite of the question because it seems it was poorly written.

I am trying to use this package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component

for dynamic component @Input() with ngFor loop variable.

The package's author has answered a [question](https://github.com/gund/ng-dynamic-component/issues/50) that seems to address my exact case. However I don't get it to work like proposed in the answer:

```
<div *ngFor="let tabComponent of tabComponents()">
  <ndc-dynamic 
     [ndcDynamicComponent]="tabComponent.component"
     [ndcDynamicInputs]="{ tabItem: tabComponent }"
  </ndc-dynamic>
</div>
```

TabContainerComponent's tabComponents -array is like this:

```
  public tabComponents: ITabComponent[] = [
    { name: 'SelectedObjects', icon: 'selected-objects', isSelected: true, component: SelectedObjectsComponent },
    { name: 'DummyComponent1', icon: 'pin', isSelected: false, component: DummyComponent },
    { name: 'DummyComponent2', icon: 'selected-objects', isSelected: false, component: Dummy2Component } 
  ]
```

and all the dynamic tab component have:

```
@Input() tabItem: any;
```

According to documentation I should add ndcDynamicInputs:inputs like below (and not inline in html:

```
<div *ngFor="let tabComponent of tabComponents()">
  <ndc-dynamic 
     [ndcDynamicComponent]="tabComponent.component"
     [ndcDynamicInputs]="inputs"
  </ndc-dynamic>
</div>
```

The problem is how to define the inputs-array in the ts class:

```
inputs = {
  // how to assign tabComponent?
  tabItem: ??
}
```

So how to assign the value of the How to assign value of *ngFor loop variable to angular dynamic component's @Input property?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056828/pass-an-input-value-into-a-ngcomponentoutlet-created-component

Comment: @Sergey: not duplicate. there's tons of questions about Inputs and Outputs in general related to ngComponentOutlet. this is specific to ng-dynamic-component.

Comment: This would would be a tab navigation that would not handle back button in a browser. Is this what you want? ex: you come from page A into page B with the tabcomponent. You press around in your tabcomponent a couple of times then hit browser back button and you go back to page A

Comment: this has nothing to do with navigation or back buttons or browser tabs.

Comment: as stated in question i want to know how to pass ngFor-loop variable to ng-dynamic-component's @Input()

Comment: @charm as far as I see your problem is around passing inputs in `ngComponentOutlet` (it doesn't matter whether you are trying to pass them to your local component or a library's component) the flow is the same. Therefore, you need to consider how to pass `Inputs` and `Outputs` to `ngComponentOutlet` and thus you will pass them to your library's component. Also there is no trace of using `ng-dynamic-component`

Comment: @Sergey: yes there is:  ndcDynamicInputs:inputs; ndcDynamicOutputs:outputs. I just use the other format. Maybe I have to rewrite this without ngComponentOutlet to emphasize even more that i am using ng-dynamic-component-package like stated in 2nd row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [ndcDynamicInputs]="inputs", have you tried [ndcDynamicInputs]="{ tabItem: tabComponent }" ?

Comment: yes, it actually works just like i wrote in the question. i naturally tried this, but i just checked value in debugging at init time and it doesn't show correct value for some reason.