# Pass angular components as array to html template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

**Context** :-Small Angular Application(only two tabs on single screen) deployed independently as static assets in AWS S3 bucket.

**Given** :- One of my Angular(12) container Component have long markup, but most of code is duplicated due to creating grid,  I have few columns in a row like below

```
<div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">{{aStringTitle}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col mt-2">
            {{differentMarkupForEachColumn}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**What I want to achieve** :- I want to render these columns using `*ngFor` passing array of following type :-

```
    [
      {name: 'First Ng Component', component: <SmallAngularComponent>},
      {name: 'Second Ng Component', component: <AnotherSmallAngularComponent>},
      ...... and so on upto 7-8 smaller angular components    
    ]
```

When I checked angular.io I could not find suitable example in template docs.

**Actual question** :- How to pass an array of Angular components to the template of a containing Angular component ?

**What I don't want** :- Alternative approach is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding), but I want to render proper Angular components and not some random html.

Comment: So you want to iterate over your array and want to create these components?

Comment: Components are already created , currently rendered as individual divs , I just wan to loop them as most of my code is duplicated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if I understood you correctly, you want to dynamically create these components in your HTML.

To do so you can simply use the `NgComponentOutlet` (see [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet) for more).

Your code would look like following:

**component.ts**

```
components = [
  { name: 'First Ng Component', component: SmallAngularComponent },
  { name: 'Second Ng Component', component: AnotherSmallAngularComponent },
  // ...... and so on upto 7-8 smaller angular components    
];
```

You might have noticed that you don't need `<>`for the components.

**component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let entry of components">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">{{ entry.name }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col mt-2">
        <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="entry.component"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

If you need to pass params to the different components you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056828/pass-an-input-value-into-a-ngcomponentoutlet-created-component) or you need to programmatically create these components.

Comment: Thank you, I could not understand, angular website needs to have some basic examples, like React.js, Initially I could not understand what is injector: myInjector; and injector.create